# Which Esperantidos are still used nowadays?

Tags: esperantidos

Many languages where created using the model of Esperanto. They are called [Esperantidos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esperantido) in English. Do some of them have an active community of users nowadays?

Comment: Answers to [this question](http://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/1082/how-many-people-speak-esperanto-compared-to-other-planned-languages) indicate that Ido is the only Esperantido with some speakers, but the numbers are extremely low.

Answer (score 4):

There is no shortage of projects at any given time with one or two supporters - or even a handful - but if you consider the Esperanto community a tiny force, the *Esperantidoj*, for all intents and purposes, do not exist.

It depends, of course, on what you mean by "used" - and how similar to Esperanto a project needs to be considered an *Esperantido.* I speak, or more exactly - have learned at least to some degree at some point, a few different *Esperantidoj*, so in at least this small way, it may (or may not) be fair to say that they are "in use."

The most obvious *Esperantido* is **Ido** and is clearly still in use, even if it is on life support. In 2005, we had a series of bits on *Radio Verda* which included a character who spoke a modified form of Ido. This initially drew some criticism from some people including some real-life Idists. Eventually, I ended up working with some of these folks to check the Ido in my bits so that when the script called for proper Ido, it would have it.

Back when I paid attention to this sort of thing, the photographs of the World Ido Convention had something like 40 or 50 people in them. There was an active book service which included some new books. There was a podcast in Ido, which is still available on YouTube. More recent photos of the world Ido events suggests to me that Ido is still in use, but that 40 people would be considered a huge event at this point. I found fairly recent pictures with 15 or 20 people. The 2016 event seems to have had about 8.

A less known Esperantido is the ***Zamenhofa Reformprojekto de 1894***. I became interested in this project in 2006. At the time, the only information that was available on the web about it was from scans of Idist material from earlier decades. I obtained a paper book (imagine that) which contained a description of the project and I produced a few short translations in it. I was unable to find anybody else anywhere other than Zamenhof and myself who had (ever) written anything in this project. I stopped paying attention and then several years later I saw that someone had put up a website with information on the reform, including new translations, and then just as quickly disappeared.

I had a similar experience with the language **Intal** - which may or may not be considered an *Esperantido*. (I would describe it as a semi-naturalistic Euroclone, but it can be written using an Esperanto dictionary.) There wasn't a whole lot of information available on it online, and then somebody somewhere revived a different revision of the language and started a conversation group in this different revision. I doubt that this is still active - but it was "in use" for a short time there even fairly recently.

**Interlingua** is also "in use" to roughly the same order of magnitude as Ido - but it probably doesn't count as an *Esperantido*. Even **NovIAL** had a few supporters in 1998 - although it seems likely they discovered the project in a book and attempted to revive it.

Answer (score 2):

Depends how many speakers you have to count before you call it "a community". Ido is probably the most well known of the languages you're talking about, and the attendees of the World Ido Congress have dinner together round a table at a local restaurant. That's not all of the world's Ido speakers of course, but it's probably a significant fraction of its fluent speakers.

Even the Esperanto community is still very thinly spread around the world, and it is orders of magnitude bigger than Ido or any other such language.